# How to suppress these fake warnings coming from aiohttp?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I've got some code that makes requests to remote sites using `asyncio` and `aiohttp`.

```
import aiohttp, asyncio

async def f():
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    async with session.get('https://httpbin.org/get') as response:
        pass

asyncio.run(f())
```

When I run it, it produces

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f56796b3d68>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7f56793836a8>, 0.0)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7f56796b3f98>
```

Now, the way I make requests is not recommended (for various reasons), which is why I'm getting those messages. However, they sure won't stop me, and so I just wish to never see them again.

I reasonably assumed that they are normal warnings and tried disabling them via the `-Wignore` command line option, as well as by putting the following code at the start of the script

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

but the messages kept appearing. How come? How can I suppress them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, `aiohttp`  not only emits normal warnings with that text, but also calls the *exception* handler of the loop with the same message during the unexceptional `__del__` invocation.

Source for [`ClientSession`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/client.py):

```
def __del__(self, _warnings: Any=warnings) -> None:
    if self._protocol is not None:
        ...
        _warnings.warn('Unclosed connection {!r}'.format(self),
                       ResourceWarning,
                       **kwargs)
        ...
        context = {'client_connection': self,
                   'message': 'Unclosed connection'}
        ...
        self._loop.call_exception_handler(context) # <---
```

Thus, if you only want to suppress the warnings that come from the `aiohttp` library *and* through the loop's exception handler, you have to either

### Replace the loop's default exception handler

For example, with a no-op function:

```
async def f():
    asyncio.get_running_loop().set_exception_handler(lambda loop, context: None)
    ...

# No output
```

or

### Change the logging level for the whole `asyncio` module

Because the loop's default exception handler logs the exception messages with the `logging.ERROR` level, you will have to set the level to `logging.CRITICAL`

```
import logging

async def f():
    logging.getLogger('asyncio').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    ...

# No output
```

Answer (score 0):

In order not to disable logging for the entire asyncio module, you can filter out a specific exception

### **Set your own exception handler**

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio.base_events import BaseEventLoop

def exc_handler(self: BaseEventLoop, context: dict) -> None:
    if context.get("message") != "Unclosed connector":
        BaseEventLoop.default_exception_handler(self, context)

asyncio.get_running_loop().set_exception_handler(exc_handler)
```

This will filter out Unclosed connector exceptions